# Batch script to launch batch xml files from a folder

Tags: batch-file, reporting, financial

I have a req where we have set of batch xml files in C:\Today\set folder and I need to execute these xml files using batch script and if these files execute successfuly goes to success.log file if they are failed then will go to error.log file and scheduleBatch.cmd is inbuit utility file which executes these xml file.Please help me out how to design the code with this req.I really appreciate your help and Thanks in advance –

Comment: It's hard to know what changes need to be done when you haven't yet told us what is/isn't working as you would expect.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

```
SET "xml_dir=%~1"
SET "hyp_server=server name"
For %%z in ("%xml_dir%\*.xml") do schedulebatch "%%~z" "%hyp_server%"
SET "RC=%ERRORLEVEL%"
EXIT /B %RC%
```

more can't be done without more explanation of your issue.

Comment: Please help me out with the above scipts